# Simulating a magnetic field in Spice

Tags: spice, magnetics, coil, multisim

I am trying to simulate a circuit that involves pickup coils in Spice. How would one simulate the magnetic fields that the pickup coils can sense? Additionally, how would one get a frequency response for such an input? (By frequency response, I mean output voltage vs input flux)

One idea I thought of is using a magnetic coupling (K) between the simulated coil and another "input" coil through which a known current can be passed. The current in the "input" coil would cause a current to flow through the simulated coil due to the coupling, and essentially simulate a field causing a current flow. The issue with this problem is that I am unable to get an output voltage frequency response based on the input current (I'm using MultiSim).

Any ideas?

Comment: I know this is old, but it sounds like your issue is that you're not using a time varying signal on the magnetically coupled "input" coil. A constant current won't result in any response on the pickup coil using this model. Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: You might consider modelling it as an air core transformer

Answer (score 1):

Model the change in field as a single ac voltage source. Add to this a resistance and inductance (pickup winding resistance and leakage inductance). For even better accuracy add some capacitance to model a bulk interwinding capacitance:

```
Lleakage 1 N1 <value>

Vac 2 N2 <func_of_time>

Rwinding 2 1  <value>

Cparasitic N1 N2 <value>
```